# jsonValidationWorkflowStack seems to be removed in Struts 2.3.1

Tags: struts2

The jsonValidationWorkflowStack seems to be removed in Struts 2.3.1, anyone knows why?

best regards

Comment: if i understand it correct, this is due to the deprecated DOJO plugin on Struts 2.1 and above.

Comment: hmm, yes, thats what I was afraid of. I replaced the depricated DOJO plugin a year ago with the jquery-plugin made by one of the german commiters to Struts 2
http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/

but its of course not part of the standard. I can try to extract the Jsonvalidation interceptor from the old version of struts and add it manually to my application and check if it works then (hope it doesnt have lots of dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

The jsonValidationWorkflowStack has moved to the json plugin. Just include the struts2-json-plugin.jar into your classpath.